# Troubleshooting a redirect after a video

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

This script should play a video then redirect to another page.

The video portion loads and plays automatically. The redirect feature does not work after the video finishes playing. The code is below:

```
<video src="http://brigadapictures.com/images/image1.m4v" autoplay height="396" width="704">

video>

var listenToMe:Object = new Object();
listenToMe.complete = function(evt) {
getURL("http://brigadapictures.com/Home.html");

}
myMediaPlayer.addEventListener("complete",listenToMe);
```

Comment: Is this Javascript or Actionscript? What does `getURL` do?

Comment: Do you know for sure that you complete event is firing i.e. have you tried a simple alert. Secondly, what is `getURL()`? If you've confirmed the event is being fired, please supply the code for `getURL()`

Comment: This looks like a mix of HTML and Actionscript.  getURL is a standard AS3 function with two arguments(URL, Target).  Mindful, xzyfer has a good suggestion.  Try that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which Mediaplayer lib do you use? Does the player run into your complete event? If it does, try the following code, instead of getURL("http://brigadapictures.com/Home.html");

```
location.href = 'http://brigadapictures.com/Home.html';
```

BTW: in IE, you have to use attachEvent, instead of addEventListener.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Internet_Explorer